# Reading data from text file and combining it with date in r

Tags: r, dataframe, ftp, data-extraction

I downloaded data from the internet. I wanted to extract the data and create a data frame. You can find the data in the following filtered data set link: http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/dv/data/index.php?category=Ozone&type=Balloon . At the bottom of the site page from the 9 filtered data sets you can choose any station. Say Suva, Fiji (SUV):

I have written the following code to create a data frame that has Launch date as part of the data frame for each file.

```
    setwd("C:/Users/")
    path = "~C:/Users/"
    files <- lapply(list.files(pattern = '\\.l100'), readLines) 
    test.sample<-do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(lines){
      data.frame(datetime = as.POSIXct(sub('^.*Launch Date : ', '', lines[grep('Launch Date :', lines)])),
                 # and the data, read in as text
                 read.table(text = lines[(grep('Sonde Total', lines) + 1):length(lines)]))
    }))
```

The files are from FTP server. The pattern of the file doesn't look familiar to me even though I tried it with `.txt`, it didn't work. Can you please tweak the above code or any other code to get a data frame.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your approach looks OK, but I don't understand what isn't working. Is it simply that the format for the date isn't exactly what asPOSIXct is expecting. Try `lubridate::dmy()`

Comment: @Richard Telford. Thank you for the hint. I tried with POSITXlt and lubridate, but it doesn't seem  to  work for me. Can you please check from the site? It is giving me a hard time.

Comment: At least in the file I opened, there is more than one space between "Launch Date" and the ":". `grep` isn't recognising the search string, and not would `sub`. You can use a regular expression to cope with any number of spaces. The code is very concise - not always a good thing!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the search string does not match "Launch Date :" does not match what is in the files (at least the one I checked).

This should work

```
lines <- "Launch Date    : 11 June 1991"
lubridate::dmy(sub('^.*Launch Date.*: ', '', lines[grep('Launch Date', lines)]))
```

Code would probably be easier to debug if you broke the problem down into steps rather than as one sentence

Comment: Your expression looks good. How can I get the values only from the data. I mean the table part of the file. I chose `(grep('Sonde Total', lines)+1)` but I got: ` Error in `(grep('Sonde Total', lines)+1):length(lines): argument of length 0`. Does this makes sense to you. And what can you say about the file type? I guess it is `.txt` what shall I put in the pattern= ' ' of the file?

Answer (score 0):

I took the following approach:

```
td <- tempdir()
setwd(td)

ftp <- 'ftp://ftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/ozwv/Ozonesonde/Suva,%20Fiji/100%20Meter%20Average%20Files/'
files <- RCurl::getURL(ftp, dirlistonly = T)
files <- strsplit(files, "\n")
files <- unlist(files)

dat <- list()
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  download.file(paste0(ftp, files[i]), 'data.txt')
  df <- read.delim('data.txt', sep = "", skip = 17)
  ld <- as.character(read.delim('data.txt')[9, ])
  ld <- strsplit(ld, ":")[[1]][2]
  df$launch.date <- stringr::str_trim(ld)
  dat[[i]] <- df ; rm(df)
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but is giving me error:  `'rying URL 'ftp://ftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/ozwv/Ozonesonde/Suva,%20Fiji/100%20Meter%20Average%20Files/fj001_1997_02_06_22.l100`
`using Synchronous WinInet calls`
`Error in download.file(paste0(ftp, files[i]), "data.txt")` : 
' cannot open URL 'ftp://ftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/ozwv/Ozonesonde/Suva,%20Fiji/100%20Meter%20Average%20Files/fj001_1997_02_06_22.l100 In addition: Warning message:
`In download.file(paste0(ftp, files[i]), "data.txt")` :
  `InternetOpenUrl failed: '9#›l'` Do you think the error is from grabbing the url?`

Comment: @G1124E I am not sure about the error.  The code works fine on my machine.